# INSERT rows from multi-dimensional array in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."users" (
    "roles" _text CHECK ((array_ndims(roles) = 2) AND (array_length(roles, 2) = 3)),
    "userId" varchar(1000) NOT NULL
);
```

Which yields the following:

```
userId     | roles
------------------
foobarbaz  | {{user,owner,123},{organization,owner,456}}
```

I have a separate table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."roles" (
    "domain" varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
    "role" varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
    "domainId" varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
    "userId" varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
);
```

I'm trying to write a query that takes the rows from the users table, and populates the roles table

so the result in the roles table would be:

```
userId     | domain       | role  | domainId
-------------------------------------------
foobarbaz  | user         | owner | 123
foobarbaz  | organization | owner | 456
```

I was looking at using the `unnest()` function, but that would split the user roles column into multiple rows. What are my best options here using a combo of `select` and `insert`?

Comment: yeah multidimensional arrays are not supported very well in postgresql , unnest only give you one level of unnested data. you probably have to handle it as  a string with UDF, in that pass using array_ndims can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

on the second thought , since you have this `CHECK ((array_ndims(roles) = 2) AND (array_length(roles, 2) = 3))`, you always have ARRAY [2,3].

this is not the cleanest but works specially if its only a one time thing :

```
insert into public.roles (userid,domain, role, domainid) 
select  "userId", roles[1][1] "domain" , roles[1][2] "role" ,roles[1][3] domainid
from users 
union all
select  userId, roles[2][1] , roles[2][2],roles[2][3]   
from users ;
```